# ASP.net route is being ignored when I specify certain file extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a route setup which handles `"{Object}/{Operation}/{Name}"`.

**Routing works perfectly if I make a request for:** `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filenameexe` *(note that no forward slash is needed when no file extension is specified)*. **The request also succeeds when I make the request:** `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filename.exe/` *(note the trailing forward-slash)*.

**But I get a 404 when I make a request for:** `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filename.exe` (this time with a file extension and no trailing forward-slash).

Everything works beautifully when using the built-in Visual Studio 2010 development asp.net web-server, but when I fire the site up in in IIS, it simply throws 404s unless I append the trailing forward-slash.

**How can I make the ASP.net routing engine less picky and accept all of the examples?**

- `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filename.exe`
- `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filenameexe`
- `http://localhost/Software/Download/Filename.exe/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845812/cant-figure-out-how-to-route-my-non-mvc-site-from-sitemap-xml-to-another-aspx-p/8846619#8846619), I think you're dealing with the same issue. You may need to specify `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`, or add an HTTP handler for `.exe` files, to make sure that ASP.NET processes requests for .exe files. If ASP.NET doesn't process the files, your route won't be followed.

Comment: If your anywhere near Charlotte NC - drinks are on me!

Comment: Spent hours looking for this, only I was trying to route .jpg instead of .exe. Thanks for the help!